# How to make the space between figures on a line small when using command 'figure'?

Tags: floats

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=6cm,height=3cm]{gaussian.eps}}
    \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=6cm,height=3cm]{star.eps}}
    \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=6cm,height=3cm]{heart.eps}}
    \label{fig:exmmmf}
\end{figure}
```

I want these three figures one by one stay closer?

Comment: It would be nice if you could post a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so we can help you more easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From simple guessing (even with the missing minimal example) I think you *just* have to add some `%` at the end of the lines, see my suggestion below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=6cm,height=3cm]{gaussian.eps}}%
    \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=6cm,height=3cm]{star.eps}}\\%
    \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=6cm,height=3cm]{heart.eps}}%
    \label{fig:exmmmf}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: subcaption example]

<del>There might be a reason that you're using the `subcaption` package, I prefer to use  the `subfig` package, where it works without the comment markers at the end of the lines...</del>

I just now learned from the [LaTeX Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Subfloats) that

> the `subfigure` and `subfig` packages are deprecated and shouldn't be used any more,

so please disregard my suggestion below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \subfloat[subcaption]{\includegraphics[width=6cm,height=3cm]{gaussian}}
    \subfloat[subcaption]{\includegraphics[width=6cm,height=3cm]{star}}
    \\
    \subfloat[subcaption]{\includegraphics[width=6cm,height=3cm]{heart}}
    \caption{Figure caption}
    \label{fig:label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: subfig example]

Comment: I wouldn't consider the LaTeX Wikibooks as fully authoritative. The package `subfigure` *is* obsolete; not the same for `subfig` that has its usages, for instance when using classes incompatible with `caption` or even disallow loading it.

Comment: @egreg Out of curiosity, what classes are incompatible with `caption`?

Comment: `revtex4-1`, for instance.